# how to get server absolute path

Tags: asp.net, client-server

I have 2 question

1. How to get absolute Uri in asp.net. 
    For example: Input: "~/Files/" , Output:"www.sampleweb.com/Files/"
2. What is the "go to root" command in url on the client side like
   server side command "~/Files/"

For example:

File location

```
myAspProjectName/Files/aa.jpg
myAspProjectName/User/bb.aspx
```

into the bb.aspx

```
<asp:image ImageUrl="~/Files/aa.jpg" id="img1" runat="server"/>
```

this work fine. But

```
<img src="~/Files/aa.jpg" alt=""/>
```

don't work

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Do you mean "how do you do this in Javascript"?

Perhaps if you expanded on what you're rying to do it would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Mark B says there is no obvious syntactic shortcut for this.

If you're doing it with the current request then you can just use `Request.Url` or for an arbitrary file you can use `Page.ResolveURL("~/some/path")` if you are using an ASP.Net page.  These are methods that will generate absolute relative URIs i.e. those of the form /path/somefile then if you then get the host name using Mark B's approach you can concatenate the two things together.

As for (2) I think you possibly mean absolute relative URIs.  If a relative URI begins with a forward slash it is resolved as being relative to the base domain e.g. if you were on the page `http://yourdomain.com/somedir/somepage.aspx` and you followed a link which was `/otherdir/somepage.aspx` you'd end up at `http://yourdomain.com/otherdir/somepage.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a shortcut syntax to map a physical path to a virtual one including the domain name. However, this will work:

```
string absoluteUri = Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"] + Request.ServerVariables["URL"];
```

Not sure what you mean by the second question - please can you expand?